# What is the permission required to access friends' stream/links?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have an app that has "friend's likes" permission, and I'm able to get their likes, but no access to their stream/links tables in FQL.
Does anybody know how to gain access to that info (their wall posts, basically)?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `read_stream` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to see their feed and links

Comment: the permissions I have are: user_likes, friends_likes, offline_access,read_stream.
is that the read_stream you're referring to?

Comment: Yep, that should give you access to the both sets of info; can you access it in the graph API?  Ttry the graph API explorer at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to check; maybe there's something else going on other than 'insufficient permission'

Answer (score 1):

There **is** no analog to the user’s read_stream permission for friends.

Means, you can’t access a user’s friends stream directly.